# Check if file been updated in 3 days and send email when IF matches a specific date

Tags: powershell, email

I have been having some issues with this specific `if` and `else` statement in PowerShell. This is the first time I am attempting an `if` and `else` statement, so please be nice.

```psh
$Trend_virus_definition_up_of_date = Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' |
    where {($_.FullName -match "<specific file.*>") –and
           ($_.LastWriteTime -ge ((get-date).AddDays(-3)))} |
    select LastWriteTime -Last 1

$Trend_virus_definition_out_to_date = Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' |
    where {($_.FullName -match "<specific file.*>") –and
           ($_.LastWriteTime -le ((get-date).AddDays(-3)))} |
    select LastWriteTime -Last 1 

$trend_EMAIL_up_to_date_email_body = $Trend_virus_definition_up_of_date  
$Trend_EMAIL_NOT_up_to_date_body = $Trend_virus_definition_out_to_date  
$Trend_OUT_ofdate_SEND_EMAIL = Send-MailMessage -From <email address> -SmtpServer "smtp" `
    -Body "Trend Virus Definitions have not been updated since '$Trend_EMAIL_NOT_up_to_date_body'" `
    -Subject "Trend Virus Definitions have not been updated since '$Trend_EMAIL_NOT_up_to_date_body'" `
    -To <email address>
$Trend_UP_TO_DATE_SEND_EMAIL = Send-MailMessage -From <email address> -SmtpServer "smtp" `
    -Body "Trend Virus Definitions were last updated '$trend_EMAIL_up_to_date_email_body'" `
    -Subject "Trend Virus Definitions UP to date - Last Update '$trend_EMAIL_up_to_date_email_body'" `
    -To <email address>

if (($Trend_virus_definition_up_of_date.LastWriteTime) -eq (get-date).AddDays(-3)) {
    $Trend_UP_TO_DATE_SEND_EMAIL
} else {
    $Trend_OUT_ofdate_SEND_EMAIL
}
```

I have been trying to get this to work and just seem to be missing something basic.

Comment: Does the code do anything? If there is output you can post, please do.

Comment: Hi. Yes it would send me 2 emails for both IF and ELSE, however the answer from Ansgar Wiechers was the correct way and it is working PERFECTLY:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. The statement

```psh
Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' | where {
  ($_.FullName -match "<specific file.*>") –and
  ($_.LastWriteTime -ge ((get-date).AddDays(-3)))
} | select LastWriteTime -Last 1
```

could be simplified to

```psh
Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' | where {
  $_.LastWriteTime -ge ((get-date).AddDays(-3))
} | select LastWriteTime -Last 1
```

because there's no need to filter for the same name twice (both in `Get-Item` and `Where-Object`).

The statement will return a date when the file was updated less then 3 days ago, otherwise the result will be `$null`. Thus you can use the returned value to decide which mail to send (PowerShell will interpret `$null` as `$false` in a boolean expression):

```psh
$definitionUpToDate = Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' | where {
  $_.LastWriteTime -ge ((get-date).AddDays(-3))
} | select LastWriteTime -Last 1

if ($definitionUpToDate) {
  $msg  = "Virus definitions up to date."
} else {
  $msg  = "Virus definitions not up to date."
}

Send-MailMessage -Subject $msg -Body $msg -From ...
```

If you want to include the date of the last update in the message you could separate fetching the date from the check:

```psh
$lastUpdate = Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' |
              select LastWriteTime -Last 1

if ($lastUpdate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-3))) {
  $msg  = "Virus definitions up to date."
} else {
  $msg  = "Virus definitions last update on $lastUpdate."
}

Send-MailMessage -Subject $msg -Body $msg -From ...
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar Wiechers. I really appreciate this! It is a MASSIVE help. I agree with the below comment that I need to get the basics of the ISE down properly. However in this case you are a true legend! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You realy miss some powershell basics. $Trend_OUT_ofdate_SEND_EMAIL = Send.... is a **variable assignment** und if you execute $Trend_OUT_ofdate_SEND_EMAIL in your if statement, you will just receive **the result of the previous call**. Thus, you have to call the Send-MailMessage function within your IF / ELSE statement:

```
$Trend_virus_definition_up_of_date = Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' | where {($_.FullName -match "<specific file.*>") –and ($_.LastWriteTime -ge ((get-date).AddDays(-3)))} | select LastWriteTime -Last 1

$Trend_virus_definition_out_to_date = Get-Item '\\<folder location>\<specific file.*>' | where {($_.FullName -match "<specific file.*>") –and ($_.LastWriteTime -le ((get-date).AddDays(-3)))} | select LastWriteTime -Last 1 

$trend_EMAIL_up_to_date_email_body = $Trend_virus_definition_up_of_date  
$Trend_EMAIL_NOT_up_to_date_body = $Trend_virus_definition_out_to_date  


if (($Trend_virus_definition_up_of_date.LastWriteTime) -eq (get-date).AddDays(-3))  
{
    Send-MailMessage -From <email address> -SmtpServer "smtp" -Body "Trend Virus Definitions were last updated '$trend_EMAIL_up_to_date_email_body'" -Subject "Trend Virus Definitions UP to date - Last Update '$trend_EMAIL_up_to_date_email_body'" -To <email address>
} 
else 
{
    Send-MailMessage -From <email address> -SmtpServer "smtp" -Body "Trend Virus Definitions have not been updated since '$Trend_EMAIL_NOT_up_to_date_body'" -Subject "Trend Virus Definitions have not been updated since '$Trend_EMAIL_NOT_up_to_date_body'" -To <email address>
}
```

Comment: Hi JisaakI really could not agree more, I do use powershell daily but more on a command basis. Your help is really appreciated and Ill go back to the drawing board and make an effort to get better at the ISE. Thanks again